# Non linear Model Fit (surface energy)

Tags: fitting

```
data = {{45.65, 38.9}, {66.87, 47.7}, {79.65, 63.4}, {36.03, 
    25.81}, {64.79, 71.99}};

soln = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
(180/pi)*ArcCos (-1 + (2*(s/l)^0.5)*(Exp[-0.0001247 (l - s)^2])),
{s}, {l}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

I think my syntax is ok, but I cannot find my error. I appreciate any help...

Comment: Use Pi, not pi, and ArcCos[...], not ArcCos(...), but even with those fixes it is still complaining about a vector of Complex values instead of Real values.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to correcting the syntax errors, having some approaching to starting values of parameters will help get desired fit, e.g. (using the definition from Nasser's correction of syntax errors and the data)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f /. s -> p, {L0, 20, 70}, Epilog -> Point@data], {p, 20, 40}]
```

[image]

so fitting:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {f, s > 0}, {{s, 35}}, {L0}, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

You can best fit for single parameter:

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

yields: {s -> 35.094}

You can explore model using `nlm["Properties"]` and there are a number of excellent answers if you search this site.

Answer (score 1):

syntax errors and not good choice of `l` as variable name as it looks like `1`. Also need a constraint added to avoid complex values errors

```
Clear[s, L0];
data = {{45.65, 38.9}, {66.87, 47.7}, {79.65, 63.4}, 
   {36.03, 25.81}, {64.79, 71.99}};
f = (180/Pi)*ArcCos [-1 + (2*(s/L0)^0.5)*(Exp[-0.0001247 (L0 - s)^2])];
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, {f, s > 0}, {s}, {L0}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
   // Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]